# Confluence: Accessing multiple values from param

Tags: confluence

I am trying to create a user macro in confluence that creates a number of links (can be however many) based on user input. The 2 params I use look like this:

```
## @param LNK:title=Link|type=string|required=true|multiple=true
## @param TTL:title=Title|type=string|required=true|multiple=true
```

The user will input something like this:

```
  Link: link_1, link_2, link_3
  Title: title_1, title_2, title_3
```

The macro should then create a list of links like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/link_1">title_1</a>; <a href="http://mysite.com/link_2">title_2</a>....
```

My question is: how can I access the content of the `LNK/TTL` param so that I can retrieve `link_1, link_2, etc`.? I need to get some kind of index so that I can correctly `link LNK[1] to TTL[1]`.

Any help is welcomed!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way (which seems a bit complicated) to do what I needed. Here's the code:

```
## @param VTP:title=VTP Number|type=string|required=true|multiple=true|desc=VTP number from JIRA (ex: VTP-1)
## @param TCI:title=Test Case Identifier |type=string|required=true|multiple=true|desc=Test Case Identifier (ex: IN_TC01)

#set ($LVTP = [])
#set ($LTCI = [])
#set ($VTP = $paramVTP.split(";"))
#set ($TCI = $paramTCI.split(";"))

#foreach ($element in $VTP)
    #set ($xxx = $LVTP.add($element))
#end

#foreach ($element in $TCI)
    #set( $xxx = $LTCI.add($element))
#end

#set ($end = ($LVTP.size() - 1))

#foreach ($i in [0..$end])
     [<a href="http://myconfluence.com/browse/$LVTP.get($i)" target="_blank">$LTCI.get($i)</a>]
#end
```

I had to do this since it seems that the only way to access the content of an array (`$VTP and $TCI` in my case) in Confluence if through the `#foreach` loop. Things like `arrays.asList` didn't work for me.

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please let me know.